# How to add question mark to the url using django?

Tags: python, regex, django, url, django-rest-framework

I have:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^tools(?:/tool_one=(?P<tool_one>\w+))?/?$', views.ToolsViews.as_view(), name='tools'),
]
```

the print of url like this:

> tools/tool_one=bags

I want to add a question mark to the url like this:

> tools/?tool_one=bags

I was try to write:

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^tools(?:/\?tool_one=(?P<tool_one>\w+))?/?$', views.ToolsViews.as_view(), name='tools'),
    ]
```

but the question mark didn't exists, the print of url:

> tools/%3Ftool_one=bags

Can anyone give me some hint? What is the problem?

Comment: That is a querystring, this is *not* part of the Django URLs.

Comment: Use `<a href="{% url 'tools' %}?tool_one={{ my_tool_one }}">`. You can obtain it in the view with `self.request.GET['tool_one']`.

Answer (score 3):

What you here describe is the *querystring*. Querystrings are *not* processed by Django URLs. You can however access the data of the querystring through `request.GET` in a function-based view, or `self.request.GET` in a class-based view.

`request.GET` is a `QueryDict`. It acts like a dictionary (except that it is immutable, and furthermore a key can map to multiple values).

You can thus obtain the value for the `tool_one` with `self.request.GET['tool_one']` (the same way you would query a dictionary).

Since this is not part of the Django urls, the `urls.py` file looks like:

```
#  app/urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^tools/$', views.ToolsViews.as_view(), name='tools'),
]
```

In the view you can then for example use this to filter, like:

```
class ToolsViews(ListView):
    model=Tool

    def get_queryset(self):
        if 'tool_one' in self.request.GET:
            return Tool.objects.filter(one=self.request.GET['tool_one'])
        return Tool.objects.all()
```

Finally you can construct such URLs in templates with:

```
<a href="{% url 'tools' %}?tool_one=foo">Link</a>
```

Or by writing a `<form>` with a `"get"` method:

```
<form action="{% url 'tools' %}" method="get">
  Tool one: <input type="text" name="tool_one"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Such form with `method="get"` will then translate the value in the textbox into the querystring.